# How to apply font int String to Html format?

Tags: android, html, fonts

I'm trying to create a String text with `impact.ttf` font?
And I need to send that String as html to my email and to see the font on my computer.
I know how to use `Typeface` but it's work only on my device.
how can I do that?

Comment: please post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Install that font to your desktop also. and such questions should not be asked here.

Comment: @GilMoshayof i do have the font on my computer